# Create a list of strongly typed variable names using Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, expression, expression-trees

I have a class:

```
public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a method:

```
public static List<string> PrintPropertyNames<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        if (p.Body is MemberExpression)
        {
            var e = (MemberExpression)p.Body;
            list.Add(((JsonPropertyAttribute)e.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute))).PropertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            var e = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)p.Body).Operand;
            list.Add(((JsonPropertyAttribute)e.Member.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute))).PropertyName);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Which I call like this:

`Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", PrintPropertyNames<Student>(x => x.Age, x => x.Country)));`

Now, I want to modify my method definition to take only one parameter, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried doing something like this:

`public static List<string> PrintPropertyNames2<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties)`

Which I call like this:

`Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", PrintPropertyNames2<Student>(new Expression<Func<Student, object>>[] { x => x.Age, x => x.Country })));`

I tried simplifying it to:

`Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", PrintPropertyNames2<Student>(new [] { x => x.Age, x => x.Country })));`

But the compiler couldn't find the best suitable type. So I have to explicitly write the type, which looks ugly and not what I really want anyways. I need it generic.

What I want to do in the final version is the following:

`Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", PrintPropertyNames<Student>(x => x.Age && x.Country && x.Name)));` (output should be - `age country name`)

I'm not sure if that's possible, but I want to put all my properties inside a single expression and obtain their json attribute value at once.

Comment: Note that `x => x.Age && x.Country && x.Name` isn't a valid expression which will compile -- `Age` is an `int` and `Name` is a `string`, and you can't combine those with `&&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you can't use `x => x.Age && x.Country && x.Name` -- `Age` is an `int` and `Name` is a `string`, and you can't combine those with `&&`, so you'll get a compiler error. But we can use `+` instead as string concatentation, or return a `new { x.Name, x.Age, x.Country }` or `new object[] { x.Name, x.Age, x.Country }`.

Either way, the easiest way to do this is to use an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitmember?view=net-5.0) to find all `MemberAccess` expressions which access a property on our input `Student`, wherever they're buried in the expression:

```
public class FindPropertiesVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression parameter;
    public List<string> Names { get; } = new List<string>();

    public FindPropertiesVisitor(Expression parameter) => this.parameter = parameter;

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression == parameter)
        {
            Names.Add(node.Member.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>().PropertyName);
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

Using this is pretty straightforward:

```
public static List<string> FindPropertyNames<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    var visitor = new FindPropertiesVisitor(expr.Parameters[0]);
    visitor.Visit(expr);
    return visitor.Names;
}
```

We pass in `expr.Parameters[0]` as the `Student` expression, which we want to find member accesses on.

You can then call it with any expression which accesses those properties in any way, e.g.:

```
var names = FindPropertyNames<Student>(x => new { x.Name, x.Age, x.Country });
var names = FindPropertyNames<Student>(x => new object[] { x.Name, x.Age, x.Country });
var names = FindPropertyNames<Student>(x => x.Name + x.Age + x.Country);
```

[See it working here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jai2CO).

Comment: I think `FindPropertyNames<Student>(x => new { x.Name, x.Age, x.Country });` an be even nicer looking  usage.

Comment: @GuruStron Fair point! Added in as examples (the code worked as-is)

Comment: @canton7 Great answer, thank you. However, I must note that the syntax with plus (last one) - `(x => x.Name + x.Age + x.Country)` does not work if there are class types. For example, if `Age` was a `public CustomAge Age {get; set;}`, it won't work.

Comment: @Axajkamkat In your specific example it will work, because `string + anything = string`. It won't work if you don't have a string as one of the first 2 things being concatted together however: you'll have to add an empty string `""` at the start somewhere. I quite like GuruStron's suggestion of an anonymous object though: that's clear

Comment: True, I've used anonymous object too. But I was adding more properties to my class, one of which was another class property and as you said, it won't work properly with string concat. Either way, the solution is pretty elegant, thank you, appreciate it!

Comment: I came across an issue using this method, hopefully maybe you can take a look at it and see if it can be fixed @canton7 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67886319/accessing-nested-properties-and-collections-using-expression